# Can't turn on external keyboard's RGB light

Tags: keyboard

I recently got a RGB keyboard, which is from a Chinese company and it's name is leorqeon kmx-50 but it's RGB light won't turn on even with all the methods people mentioned here...
Do I have to give up rgb light?

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details, so why ask here?  You also make mention of "*methods people mentioned here*" but it's unclear what you meant with "*here*".  This isn't a hardware support site, so why ask here?

Comment: *methods people mentioned here* are methods for software controlled backlight in Ubuntu with alternatives to the manufacturer's provided Windows software/driver. Yours has no such thing. Backlight is controlled with FN+a special key. Please read your user's manual.